# How to set prefixed user schemas in search_path?

Tags: postgresql

We prefix schemas in order to distinguish their types. Data schemas start with `d_`, team schemas with `t_` and user schemas with `u_`.

How do I set search_path in order for user `example` to create table *automatically* in the schema `u_example`?

I tried `ALTER ROLE example SET search_path TO "u_$user",public` but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that automatically.

If you insist on that naming, you'd have to run an `ALTER ROLE` statement per user.